# How to send a .m4a to flask server on Android with OkHttp?

Tags: java, python, android, flask, okhttp

I am trying to upload an audio .m4a file (that I recorded with my app) to my Flask server, using OkHttp3, in Android Studio.
The file should be uploaded to the server after I press the "STOP" button.
Here is the code that I have until now:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.audiorecorder;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.squti.androidwaverecorder.WaveRecorder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int MICROPHONE_PERMISSION_CODE = 200;
private static int STORING_PERMISSION_CODE = 300;
private static int READING_PERMISSION_CODE = 300;

MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (isMicrophonePresent()) {
        getMicrophonePermission();
        getStoringPermission();
        getReadingPermission();

    }
}

public void btnRecordPressed(View v) {

    try {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16*96000);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getRecordingFilePath());

        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording is started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void btnStopPressed(View v) {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.release();
    mediaRecorder = null;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // String postUrl = "http://192.168.1.15:5000/uploader";


}

public void btnPlayPressed(View v) {


    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getRecordingFilePath());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        String msg = "Playing: " + getRecordingFilePath();
        textView.setText(msg);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean isMicrophonePresent() {
    if (this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void getMicrophonePermission() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MICROPHONE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}

private void getStoringPermission() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORING_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}

private void getReadingPermission() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READING_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}

private String getRecordingFilePath() {
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File musicDirectory = contextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
    File file = new File(musicDirectory,"testRecordingFile" + ".m4a");
    return file.getPath();
}

public static void upload(String path) throws IOException {

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    String filename = getRecordingFilePath();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().build();

    
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Prediction:"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
    android:onClick="btnRecordPressed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="record"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:onClick="btnStopPressed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="stop"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
    android:onClick="btnPlayPressed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="play"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

@app.route('/uploadfile',methods=['GET','POST'])
def uploadfile():
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        f = request.files['file']
        filePath = "./"+secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(filePath)
        return 'success'
```

Or, is there an easier method to send the file to the server ?
I would really appreciate if you could help me with this.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This is how to create the MultiPart object.

```
RequestBody postBodyAudio = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("audio", "testRecordingFile.m4a", 
RequestBody.create(getFileBytes(),MediaType.parse("audio/*m4a")))
            .build();
```

getFileBytes() returns the byte array of the audio file

```
private byte[] getFileBytes() throws IOException {
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File musicDirectory = contextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
    File file = new File(musicDirectory,"testRecordingFile" + ".m4a");
    byte bytes[] = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
    return bytes;
}
```

I used this library to convert a file to a byte array

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray(java.io.File)

If you want to use it, type this dependency into the gradle file

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
```